# How to downgrade react native version while creating project, not after

Tags: reactjs, react-native

previously we were using react native ver 0.59.0 and somehow it's upgraded to ver 0.60.3. As we know that their many major changes in this version, so now with the latest versions we are facing many issues in the development. So are there any ways to downgrade it to ver 0.59.0 again.
So please suggest us anyway to do the same.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify which React Native version to use when creating the project through the CLI by passing the `version` flag:

`react-native init newproject --version react-native@0.59.0`